# How do I make an extend method that works like Backbone's, using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, extends

I would like to use jQuery's extend method to create a method that does this:

```
var a = foo.extend({bar:'a'});
var b = new a({});
// b instanceof a => true
```

In other words, I would like `extend` to create a class. 
How do I do it?

Comment: Have you looked at the source code? That's your first stop for things like this. Also, I think this is covered in Effective Javascript somewhere.

Comment: Backbone uses Underscore, and I want to use jQuery.

Comment: It's a poor question but there's no need to keep downvoting him.

Comment: People will vote how they see fit @nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var foo = {};
foo.ext = function () {
    var Extended = function () {
         // do something with arguments
    }
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    args.unshift(Extended.prototype);
    $.extend.apply($, args);
    return Extended;
};
var a = foo.ext({bar: 'a'}, {baz: 2}, ...);
var b = new a({});
```